# Single quotes in OS X Dvorak keyboard in TextMate

Tags: macos, keyboard, textmate, quotes, dvorak

I'm using a dvorak layout in OS X in TextMate. When I type the single quote key (the q key in qwerty) I get curly single quotes like this: ’

I only want simple single quotes like this: '

I can't seem to find the key to type simple quotes or whatever you call them. Any idea?

Comment: Use the Keyboard and Character viewer?  If you don't have it enabled, you can enable it through the System Preferences/keybaord.

Comment: I did, still can't find the key I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just installed TextMate and get normal single quotes.  Could be an OS version setting rather than a TextMate setting.  I'm running 10.6.8 but I see that you originally tagged the question as OSX-Lion.   [OS X Lion: Use curly quotation marks and em dashes](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH4513)